Hyperbolic paraboloids as solutions to Laplace's equation
I decided to try my hand at solving Laplace's equations in as many ways as I could, and I've come across the result that non-rotated conic sections (those which do not depend on $xy$ arise naturally as a solution to Laplace's equation in 2 dimensions). I don't quite understand why conic sections would appear when solving this equation. I begin by writing it down:
$$\nabla^2\phi(x,y)=0$$
and then imposing that variables are separated as a sum:
$$\phi(x,y)=X(x) + Y(y)$$
Therefore, I immediately get from this imposition that:
$$\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}=0$$
Now, doing $\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}=k, \ k\in \mathbb{R}$, I get the following system of second order ODEs:
\begin{cases}
\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}=k
\\
\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}=-k
\end{cases}
Solving this system, I get:
$$X(x) = \frac{1}{2}kx^2+\tilde{A}x+\tilde{B}$$
$$Y(y)=-\frac{1}{2}ky^2+\tilde{C}y+\tilde{D}$$
Now, since my solution is, by hypothesis, the sum of these two, I get:
$$\phi(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}k(x^2-y^2)+\tilde{A}x + \tilde{C}y+\tilde{B} + \tilde{D}$$
Renaming all thes terms, I end up with a solution of the form:
$$\phi(x,y)=A(x^2-y^2)+Bx+Cy+D$$
I recognize this solution as a displaced hyperbolic paraboloid, if I'm not mistaken. Nonetheless, I don't quite understand why I would get such a specific cuadric section for what seems to be a random and restrictive imposition.

Nothing surprizing : a hyperbolic paraboloid, with reference equation $z=f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ or $z=xy$ is the "archetype" of a harmonic function ($\Delta f=0$)
